# Is there "check and get" operator against not-null in C# 8.0?

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0

As for checking type we have single operator which effectively does two things at once:

```
if (GetObject() is DateTimeOffset dto)
{
   // use dto here
}
```

Not only `dto` in this example is of specific type `DateTimeOffset` but also the value is local and it is fully evaluated.

So, does C# 8.0 provides similar operator for checking against non-null values?

```
if (GetPossibleNull() is not null x)
{
  // x is local, evaluated and guaranteed to be not-null
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to check against non-null values?

Comment: I'm not sure, thats what you meant: `a is {}` will return true, if `a` is not `null`.

Comment: @GSerg, I updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an empty Property Pattern (`{}`) to check, that an variable is not `null`

```cs
if (GetPossibleNull() is {} x)
{
  // x is local, evaluated and guaranteed to be not-null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `x is T y` expression also checks for `null` values all types (reference-types and `Nullable<T>`), even if `x` is statically typed as `T` already - and this works in C# 7.0:

```
class Foobar {}

static Foobar GetPossibleNull() { return null; }

static void Main()
{
    if( GetPossibleNull() is Foobar foobar )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "GetPossibleNull() returned a non-null value." );    
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "GetPossibleNull() returned null." );
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I see "GetPossibleNull() returned null" in the console window.

These variations also work as-expected in C# 7.3 (I don't have access to a C# 8.0 compiler right now):

```
static Nullable<Int32> GetNullInt32() => null;
static Nullable<Int32> GetNonNullInt32() => 123;

static void Main()
{
    if( GetNullInt32() is Int32 nonNullInt )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "GetNullInt32() returned a non-null value." );    
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "GetNullInt32() returned null." );
    }

    if( GetNonNullInt32() is Int32 nonNullInt )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "GetNonNullInt32() returned a non-null value." );    
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "GetNonNullInt32() returned null." );
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
GetNullInt32() returned null.

GetNonNullInt32() returned a non-null value.
```

Comment: It is correct, but this is fragile. When I rework my code, and change the result type it might happen I am using types from the same line of hierarchy so I don't even spot the bug I introduced. And besides the principle of single responsibility is not just saying, here it is example when it also applies -- solution provided by Pretasoc performs this task and ONLY this task, no side effects, bomb proof.

Comment: @astrowalker You could also change the static type declaration to a generic type parameter. That said, I don't believe the code in my answer violates the SRP.

Comment: The question was "check against not-null", your code checks if the expression is of non-nullable type T. Those problems are similar, but not the same.

Comment: @astrowalker "your code checks if the expression is of non-nullable type T."  - This is not what my code does: in the case of at least C# 7.x (I'm unsure about how it handles non-nullable reference types in C# 8.0) it checks if the **value** of a nullable type is non-null - that's why it correctly handles `GetNonNullInt32` even though it returns a `Nullable<Int32>` value (notice the method does not return an `Int32`-typed value but a `Nullable<Int32>`-typed value).